# Function not called by reference causes self.root to be None

Tags: python, python-2.7, binary-search-tree, pass-by-reference

```
class node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.left=None
        self.right=None
class btree:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root=None

    def insertt(self,root, data):
        if root==None:
            root=node(data)
        elif root.data > data:
            self.insertt(self,root.left, data)
        else:
            self.insertt(self,root.right, data)
    def insert(self,data):
        self.insertt(self.root, data)
    def printall(self):
        self.printtall(self.root)
    def printtall(self,root):
        if root==None:
            print "reached end "
        else:
            printtall(root.left)
            print root.data
            printtall(root.right)

a=btree()
a.insert(2)
a.insert(1)
a.insert(6)
a.insert(3)
a.printall()
```

So the self.root is always None. I am a C++ programmer and I am finding it hard to deal with Python as call by reference is not found here. What should I do to make it work? Thanks for your help.

Comment: If root is none you return the root (when inserting). Returning terminates the function.

Comment: @syntonym yeah but returning will also store it in some variable right? You can't add anything to that variable which would affect in the real one. If you're right please post your version of code.

Comment: @TomKarzes could you post your version of the same code ? please edit it

Comment: @TomKarzes, there had to be no return in insertt, that was a mistake.. look at it now

Comment: it is reachable as I removed return. I have checked it using putting a print statement. But the case is that nothing is being reflected as it is pass by value.

Comment: @julivico, that's pretty wrong! You don't understand bst either that means. All the time you are advising to change the self.root (the main root and not the subsequents)?

Comment: @UlsaMinor: sr, that was wrong of me. But `root=node(data)` will never set `self.root` as `node(data)`. It will create new reference.

Comment: I posted a complete solution to this.  Take a look and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code, I'll explain the problems in the comments.

```
class node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.left=None
        self.right=None
class btree:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def insertt(self, root, data):
        if root==None:
            #earlier you tried to return here which leads to dead end.
            self.root = node(data)
        else:    
            #You need the assign the data here, as if you'll
            #try to update in the above if statement you are doing 
            #nothing but just updating the root again and again
            if root.data > data:
                if root.left == None:
                    root.left = node(data)
                else:    
                    self.insertt(root.left, data)
            else:
                if root.right == None:
                    root.right = node(data)
                else:    
                    self.insertt(root.right, data)
    def insert(self,data):
        self.insertt(self.root, data)
    def printtall(self,root):
        #inorder traversal
        if root != None:
            self.printtall(root.left)
            print (root.data)
            self.printtall(root.right)
    def printall(self):
        self.printtall(self.root)


a=btree()
a.insertt(a.root, 2)
a.insertt(a.root, 1)
a.insertt(a.root, 6)
a.insertt(a.root, 3)
a.printall()
```

Output -

```
1
2
3
6
```

Comment: So when you are calling the function self.insertt(self.root, data), a copy of self.root goes there. Isn't it? Python doesn't support call by reference. How does it work then?

Comment: Well, the first if statement runs only one time, thats clear right? I edited the code, `seld.root.left` was a wrong call. What it does is always call left **with respect to the root**. Python is call by object reference, you'll get how it works from this source, it explains it really well...

Comment: http://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution to this.  Note that I changed the class names to mixed case to follow standard conventions and to make it easier to avoid name conflicts.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class BTree(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def insert(self, data):
        self.root = self.insertt(self.root, Node(data))

    def insertt(self, root, node):
        if root == None:
            root = node
        elif node.data < root.data:
            root.left = self.insertt(root.left, node)
        else:
            root.right = self.insertt(root.right, node)

        return root

    def printall(self):
        self.printtall(self.root, 0)

    def printtall(self, root, indent):
        if root == None:
            print ". " * indent + "(empty)"
        else:
            print ". " * indent + str(root.data)
            self.printtall(root.left, indent + 1)
            self.printtall(root.right, indent + 1)

a = BTree()
a.insert(2)
a.insert(1)
a.insert(6)
a.insert(3)
a.printall()
```

Here's the output.  I changed the print function to use prefix rather than infix ordering, because I found it to be clearer, but you can easily change it back if you prefer:

```
2
. 1
. . (empty)
. . (empty)
. 6
. . 3
. . . (empty)
. . . (empty)
. . (empty)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a return statement before the assignment to the root in the function "insertt"

Comment: Tried but couldn't make it work. How would you use the return statement for the same. Could you post an edited version of the above code for the same?